# Avoid executing a function (redirect) if I'm in the admin area

Tags: wp-admin, redirect

I've built this function that allows me to redirect users based on their countries, it seems to work fine for all the pages other than the admin section. Obviously, I don't want redirect if I'm in the admin section but at the moment I get a redirect loop and an error.

This is my function:

```
function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}




add_action ('after_setup_theme', 'my_redirect_function');

function my_redirect_function() {

    if (!current_user_can('administrator') || ( !is_admin() ) ) {

      $ip = '';

         if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
         {
           $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
         }
         elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
         {
           $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
         }
         else
         {
           $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
         }

         //echo $ip . "<br>";

         //$country = file_get_contents('http://geoip.maxmind.com/a?l=6QT6fNSdtMVw&i='.$ip);

     $country = url_get_contents('http://geoip.maxmind.com/a?l=6QT6fNSdtMVw&i='.$ip);

         //echo $country;

         if( $country == 'IE'  && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE != 'ie' ) {
             $current_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
             // CHANGE 2 WITH 1 ONCE THE WEBSITE IS LIVE
             if( $current_uri[1] == 'projects' ) {
               $current_uri[1] = 'projects-ie';
               $current_uri = $current_uri[1];
               // DELET /ROOFING/ ONCE THE WEBISTE IS LIVE
               $current_uri = $current_uri . "/";
               echo $current_uri . "<br>";
               $current_url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $current_uri;
               $translated_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $current_url, 'ie' );
               echo $current_url . "<br>";
               echo $translated_url;
               wp_redirect( $translated_url );
               exit;
             } else {
         $current_url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
             $translated_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $current_url, 'ie' );
             wp_redirect( $translated_url );
             echo $current_url;
             echo $translated_url;
             exit;
     }
         } elseif ( $country == 'CA'  && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE != 'can' ) {
             $current_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
             // CHANGE 2 WITH 1 ONCE THE WEBSITE IS LIVE
             if( $current_uri[1] == 'projects' ) {
               $current_uri[1] = 'projects-can';
               $current_uri = $current_uri[1];
               // DELET /ROOFING/ ONCE THE WEBISTE IS LIVE
               $current_uri = $current_uri . "/";
               echo $current_uri . "<br>";
               $current_url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $current_uri;
               $translated_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $current_url, 'can' );
               echo $current_url . "<br>";
               echo $translated_url;
               wp_redirect( $translated_url );
               exit;
             } else {
             $current_url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
             $translated_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $current_url, 'can' );
             wp_redirect( $translated_url );
             echo $current_url;
             echo $translated_url;
             exit;
           }
         }

    }

}
```

I tried to add !is_admin in this part

if (!current_user_can('administrator') || ( !is_admin() ) ) {

to avoid executing the function when I'm in the admin area but I still get the redirect loop.

I've tried different solutions but I've always got the redirect loop when I tried to accesses to the admin area.

Which statement could I use to avoid running this function on the admin area but just on the website?

New code with one more if statement:

```
add_action ('after_setup_theme', 'my_redirect_function');

function my_redirect_function() {
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') ) {

      $ip = '';

         if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
         {
           $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
         }
         elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
         {
           $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
         }
         else
         {
           $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
         }

         //echo $ip . "<br>";

         //$country = file_get_contents('http://geoip.maxmind.com/a?l=6QT6fNSdtMVw&i='.$ip);

     $country = url_get_contents('http://geoip.maxmind.com/a?l=6QT6fNSdtMVw&i='.$ip);

         //echo $country;

         if( $country == 'IE'  && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE != 'ie' ) {
             $current_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
             // CHANGE 2 WITH 1 ONCE THE WEBSITE IS LIVE
             if( $current_uri[1] == 'projects' ) {
               $current_uri[1] = 'projects-ie';
               $current_uri = $current_uri[1];
               // DELET /ROOFING/ ONCE THE WEBISTE IS LIVE
               $current_uri = $current_uri . "/";
               echo $current_uri . "<br>";
               $current_url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $current_uri;
               $translated_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $current_url, 'ie' );
               echo $current_url . "<br>";
               echo $translated_url;
               wp_redirect( $translated_url );
               exit;
             } else {
         $current_url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
             $translated_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $current_url, 'ie' );
             wp_redirect( $translated_url );
             echo $current_url;
             echo $translated_url;
             exit;
     }
         } elseif ( $country == 'CA'  && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE != 'can' ) {
             $current_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
             // CHANGE 2 WITH 1 ONCE THE WEBSITE IS LIVE
             if( $current_uri[1] == 'projects' ) {
               $current_uri[1] = 'projects-can';
               $current_uri = $current_uri[1];
               // DELET /ROOFING/ ONCE THE WEBISTE IS LIVE
               $current_uri = $current_uri . "/";
               echo $current_uri . "<br>";
               $current_url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $current_uri;
               $translated_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $current_url, 'can' );
               echo $current_url . "<br>";
               echo $translated_url;
               wp_redirect( $translated_url );
               exit;
             } else {
             $current_url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
             $translated_url = apply_filters( 'wpml_permalink', $current_url, 'can' );
             wp_redirect( $translated_url );
             echo $current_url;
             echo $translated_url;
             exit;
           }
         }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: just to make sure, have you tested when you are logged out? Because !current_user_can('administrator') will return false in the frontend/public facing site only you are logged out as admin

Comment: Hi thank you for answering me, this is driving me crazy, I just updated the code and edited my question I create new parent IF statement with (!is_admin) so the first check is for the admin page and after there is the !current_user_can('administrator') check. Now I don't get the redirect loop anymore but I get redirected when I get /wp-login.php and as a result I get a 404 error because the URL is redirected to /ie/ (www.mydomain.com/ie/wp-login.php/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.deaneroofing.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1). How can I avoid /ie/ at this stage?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a WordPress core function to check if we are in the login or register page, but we can create one using the `$pagenow` global as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5892694/3594287).

```
function is_login_page() {
    return in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) );
}
```

Then we can use this function in a [Guard Clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)), which, is a nice way to [avoid nested conditionals](https://carlalexander.ca/mastering-php-conditionals/):

```
function my_redirect_function() {

    // exit early if is in admin site or login/register pages
    if ( is_admin() || is_login_page() ) {
        return;
    }

    // check for a specific capability is a better practice as we can have
    // a more granular control of who can or can't do something
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        // do your thing in here
    }
}
```

I hope it helps. Please note that I checked for a [specific capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table) instead of a role because it allows a more granular control of who can or can't do something.